# Disable listview checkbox

Tags: android, listview

I'm using a `simple_list_item_checked` listview and am programmatically setting checked to true / false. However, when a user selects an item from the list, it changes the state of the checkbox.

It only shows it for a second, because it immediately redirects to another activity.

How can I prevent the checkbox from changing when the user clicks on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom ArrayAdapter class, following this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

But instead of using if String.equals(" "), I used a boolean value called checked. If it's true, use a "checked box" image and if false, use an "unchecked box" image.

Thanks for the help guys. I hope this is help to people in the future.

Answer (score 5):

change your CheckBox clickable property to false programatically as follows

```
theCheckBox.setClickable(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you only need to overwrite the `onListItemClick()` method of the `ListActivity`, if you use this class as base class for your `Activity`.

Then you can use the `setItemChecked()` method of the `ListView` passed as argument to control the state of the checkbox. I'm using in a project a `simple_list_item_single_choice` listview and it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `AdapterView` instance of simple_list_item_checked.  That will solve your problem.